# Looping array for largest number using forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to pull the largest number of an array using a forEach Javascript method. This is what I have so far, but I know it's not correct.

```js
var arr = [2,3,4];
var largest = 0;
 
arr.forEach(function(elem){
  if(largest < elem) 
  largest = elem;
  console.log(largest);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work

```
var arr = [2,3,4];
var largest = 0;

arr.forEach(function(elem){
  if(largest < elem) 
  largest = elem;
});

console.log(largest);
```

but why would you even do that? Why not use Math max?

```
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

To cover negative numbers in array, it is safe to assign `largest` to be the first element in array.

```js
var arr = [2,3,4];
var largest = arr[0];
 
arr.forEach(function(elem){
  if(largest < elem) 
  largest = elem;
});
console.log(largest);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use spread operator:

```js
var arr = [2,3,4];
var largest = Math.max(...arr); 
console.log(largest);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put `console.log(largest);` outside forEach loop, it will print the largest number in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
    a = [2,3,4,2,1,9],
    largest = 0;

a.forEach(function(value){
    console.log('current array element value: ' + value + '.  Is it larger than the largest?', (largest > value));
    if (largest < value) largest = value;
    console.log('largest value now is: ', largest);
});
console.log('largest is changed here, because it was not redefined inside the function of the forEach method: ', largest, '.\n But it was defined within its context.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function greatest(array) {
    if(array == undefined){
        console.log('There are no elements in array.');
    }

    const max = array.reduce(function(first, next){
        return first > next ? first : next; 
    });

    console.log(`Maximum element is ${max}`);
}
```